# Can you maintain a consideration?

Tags: meaning, verbs, nouns, collocation

More than 1 person has stumbled on this line in a draft report here:

> "...such that the considerations outlined in Section 1.2 are maintained"

Can you maintain a consideration?

Yes, the considerations are actually maintainable.

I wrote it, so it works for me, but if others are clunking on it, I wonder...

Other iterations include '*suggestions*' in place of consideration, and '*upheld*' in place of maintained.

(Would that make a difference?)

...usually, I'd just change it - no point being correct if people aren't getting the intended message - but it's interesting anyway.

Comment: You answer your own question:  if the considerations are maintainable, then they can be maintained.

Comment: @Jim, It's my belief that it is valid, but more than 1 person has stumbled on this line in a draft report here.    Unrelated, but I've just realised I've likely asked the question with a bias, nought to do about that but smile :)

Comment: Try *observed* : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=considerations+must+be+observed%2C+considerations+must+be+maintained%2C+considerations+must+be+upheld&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconsiderations%20must%20be%20observed%3B%2Cc0

Comment: They probably stumble because most people immediately think of consideration as "careful thought", but a consideration (a fact or a motive taken into account in deciding something) can definitely be maintained.

Comment: Observed: "notice or perceive (something) and register it as being significant" - yes, the significance part works well ...  I like that.

Comment: Well it might all turn upon what Section 1.2 says about the 'considerations'.  A consideration can be a thought, or a fact or circumstance taken into account, but it can also be (Oxford English Dictionary):

_Something given in payment; a reward, remuneration; a compensation, equivalent. ...1868 M. Pattison Suggestions on Academical Organisation 4.93 'The income of this fellowship forms no part of the consideration paid for tuitional services.'_

So the phrase may mean, or being misinterpreted to mean, that a payment is maintained, which is to say 'continued'.